# Hide all other rows with same class except the one clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having some issues hiding all other rows except the one clicked with jQuery.

```
$('tr .assign').live('click', function(e) {
    var element = $(this);
    var id = $(this).data('employeeID');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://domain.com/assign/'+ $(this).data('id')
    }).success(function() {
        element.text('Unassign');
        element.removeClass('assign').addClass('unassign');
        element.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-inverse');
        $("tr:has(.signup_" + id + ")").hide();
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Basically, each employee pulled from the database will have a a row in a table similar to the one below. If the "Assign" link is clicked, I want to hide all other rows within the table with the same employee id class, but keep the row that was clicked visible.

```
<tr class="signup_{{ $employeeID }}">
<td style="text-align:center;">{{ $employeeName }}</td>
<td style="text-align:center;"><a data-id="{{ $employeeID }}" class="btn btn-mini btn-success assign">Assign</a></td>
</tr>
```

With this code, no rows are hidden. However, if I change `tr:has` to `tr:not`, all the rows **except** the ones with the same signup_employeeID class are hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the parent row and then filter the `tr`s using `.not()`

```
var $trs = $("tr .assign");
$('tr .assign').live('click', function(e) {
    var element = $(this);
    var this_row = element.closest("tr"); //<-- we get the parent row
    var id = $(this).data('employeeID');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://domain.com/assign/'+ $(this).data('id')
    }).success(function() {
        element.text('Unassign');
        element.removeClass('assign btn-success')
        .addClass('unassign btn-inverse'); //<-- ignore this bit if you want.. just a simplification
        $("tr.signup_" + id).not(this_row).hide(); // <-- hide all except the one we specified earlier
    });
});
```

Comment: Well spotted, but you should use `closest` instead of `parents` as you aren't guaranteed to only have one `tr` ancestor

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
var $assignRows = $("tr .assign");
$assignRows.live('click', function(e) {
    var element = $(this);
    var id = $(this).data('employeeID');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://domain.com/assign/'+ $(this).data('id')
    }).success(function() {
        element.text('Unassign');
        element.removeClass('assign').addClass('unassign');
        element.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-inverse');
        $assignRows.not(element).hide(); // Here
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Here is a [basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrnr2/) demonstrating the .not functionality.

Also, consider switching to using [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead of .live - it's been deprecated for a [long time](https://api.jquery.com/live/) now.

Comment: I think `$assignRows.not(element);` needs to be `$assignRows.not(element).hide();` ?

Comment: I'm assuming `element` is a button.. so filtering on that won't work... we need to filter on the row, see my answer

Comment: RGraham, thanks for your suggestion; however, ekhaled is right, it did not filter through correctly, and instead, only hid the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines could work for you?

```
$('tr').live('click', function(e) {
    var element = $(this);
    $('tr:visible').hide();
    element.show();
});
```

You will, obviously, need to adjust it to work for your case, but it should be a good starting point.